# ImageMapType radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm a bit new with Google Maps API, so I don't know if the following question is well asked.

I'm trying to create a v3 powered custom map for a game world. I will use [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) to ask my question. Lets say I want to limit how far user can go up North or South. Unlike real planet, game map is not connected from sides, and in [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) is not connected from North to South. If you will try to max zoom out, and go North, drag the map to the North as much as you can, you will see how it runs out of tiles, and shows gray default background instead. I want to *limit* this North going behaviour.

I guess that `radius` property in [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) has to do something with it, but playing with it didn't help.

Is there another option as to how to limit it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first: the radius-property used in this script is without any meaning.

Basically you can't restrict the bounds of the map to a given area.
The only thing you can do is to observe a `bounds_changed`- event and when the bounds are not within the restricted area revert the bounds.

But this may have some undesired effects.

Instead you may disable the dragging of the map and use a custom pan-control, which allows the user a limited panning to north/south